# Equation for adjoint transformation and proof.

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

I am really lost on this one. Any help would be appreciated. I'm very confused.

Answer (score 1):

One has $T(\lambda x+\mu y) =<\lambda x+\mu y>z=\lambda T(x)+\mu T(y)$ thanks to the (bi)linearity of the inner product.

Now by definition of the adjoint operator we should have $\langle T(x),t\rangle=\langle x,T^*(t)\rangle$

One has $\langle T(x),t\rangle=\langle x,y\rangle\langle z,t\rangle$
So one can see that $T^*(t)=\overline{\langle z,t\rangle} y$

$\forall x T(x)\propto z$ and $\forall x T^*(x)\propto y$

In both cases the rank is $1$

Comment: Use \langle instead of <

Comment: Ok will edit accordingly

Comment: You're right @daw didn't see the typo. From my smartphone it is less convenient than from a desktop. Will edit